# How can you get a jungle seed on Minecraft PE? Or can you not?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to find a jungle, but I cannot find one. How do I find one?

Answer (score 1):

Jim's method is about as good as it gets unless you don't require the world to be random. What I mean by 'not being random' is by using a seed where someone has identified a jungle at the game spawn point. Here are a few such seeds:

[Large Jungle Biome](https://mcpehq.com/minecraft-pe-seeds/jungle/huge-jungle-biome-seed-minecraft-pe-0-14/) - Seed:nopen

[Jungle Island](https://mcpehq.com/minecraft-pe-seeds/jungle/minecraft-pe-seed-large-jungle-island/) - Seed:agpiox

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Jungles can be determinantly generated in random worlds. You just need to look hard to find one. I cannot find any suggested seeds for Minecraft: Pocket Edition, but all it takes is not just luck, but you need to try hard to find a Jungle. If you can't find a Jungle in one world, make another world and find one! If not, rinse and repeat. Make sure you made the worlds at "random seed".

Answer (score 0):

When you create a world there are the seed "window" and there is a button --->
And you can tap on your seed.this is in newest mcpe.